# Does $\neg(x > y)$ imply that $y \geq x$?

Tags: inequality, relations, propositional-calculus

Given any arbitrary binary relation $\geq$ defined on some set $S$, we define a new binary relation $>$ on $S$ by:
$$
x > y \quad\text{iff}\quad (x \geq y) \wedge \neg(y \geq x)
$$
In accordance with our usual intuition for inequalities, I would like to prove that:

> **Claim:**
>   $$
> \neg(x > y) \quad\text{iff}\quad y \geq x
> $$

Unfortunately, all I could conclude was that:
$$
\neg(x > y) \quad\text{iff}\quad \neg(x \geq y) \vee (y \geq x)
$$

Is my claim even true? If so, could somehow help me finish off my work? If not, what additional hypotheses should be added in order to salvage the claim?

Comment: Consider two elements $x,y$ such that $\neg(x\geq y)$ and $\neg (y \geq x)$. Then, according to the definition of $x>y$, we have $\neg(x>y)$, showing the claim is false.

Comment: Consider as $\ge$ the equality relation; then $x>y$ holds for no pair, hence $\lnot(x>y)$ holds for *all* pairs, while $y\ge x$ holds only when $x$ and $y$ are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is not true. Consider $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ with $x\leq y$ being $x\subseteq y$. If $\lnot(x\subsetneq y)$ then it's not necessarily that $y\subseteq x$. It might be that neither is a subset of the other.

That is to say, if we don't assume that $\leq$ is a total relation to begin with, i.e. $\forall x\forall y(x\leq y\lor y\leq x)$, then there is no way to infer what you want to conclude.